# Issues with importing THREE.js modules

Tags: javascript, import, module, three.js

I'm trying to import the custom geometry "OutlinesGeometry.js" from https://plnkr.co/edit/uEYo6L3pgbIaYXXzVzXd?preview

I'm trying to import following way:

```
<script type="module" src="./three/build/three.module.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="./three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script type="module" src="./three/examples/jsm/libs/dat.gui.min.js"></script>

<script type="module" src="./OutlinesGeometry.js"></script>
```

This gives me following errors:
[image]

First I did not import `three`, `OrbitControls` and `dat.gui` as modules, as everything worked fine (see imports below). But as soon I'm importing the `OutlinesGeometry` I received following error: `Uncaught TypeError: class constructors must be invoked with 'new'`. Because of that I'm importing the modules.

```
<script src="./three/build/three.js"></script>
<script src="./three/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
<script src="./three/examples/js/libs/dat.gui.min.js"></script>

<script src="./OutlinesGeometry.js"></script>
```

How should the imports be done correctly?

Answer (score 1):

The runtime error happens because you are deriving from a ES6 class via ES5 syntax.

In newer releases `BufferGeometry` is a ES6 class. When creating a custom geometry generator, the following code is invalid:

```js
THREE.BufferGeometry.call( this );
```

You can only solve this issue by migrating `OutlinesGeometry` to an ES6 class as well.

BTW: When working with modules, you just have a single `<script type="module"></script>` tag and use inside of the tag ES6 import syntax. Meaning:

```
<script type="module">

    import * as THREE from './three/build/three.module.js';
    import OrbitControls from './three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls.js';
```

I suggest you study the official `three.js` example for more details.